# Xcode: How to find something only in specific file type?

Tags: xcode

In Android Studio, I could search something in certain file type using the `File mask` as shown below. e.g. I could search on Kotlin (*.kt) files only
[image]

In Xcode, is it possible to do so as well? E.g. I would like to search only on the Swift file (*.swift). I don't see any filter as shown below, other than `Ignore/Matching Case`

[image]

Comment: There is a "Filter" field at the bottom of the Find Navigator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below the search field, there's an icon with three dots and a line above and below. In the default case, "In Workspace" is printed next to it.

Click this icon/text and a list of scopes is shown. Click the "+ New Scope…".

You can define complex rules for your scope, but in your case you would just need one: select `File extension` in the attribute field, `is equal to` in the condition field and `swift` in the value field.

You can give your scope a name and save it if you need it often.

---

But there is also a second solution: just do your search. At the very bottom of the search panel you see a circle icon with three lines, similar to the "ground" symbol used in electrics (IMHO); next to it is a text field with placeholder "Filter". Enter `*.swift` here to filter the search results for hits in Swift files.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way and arguably quicker way to do it is to just type the extension in the filter section below the list of matches.

[image]